# XProc: set output language

Tags: xml, xslt, locale, xproc

I have an XSL stylesheet which formats a date in a given locale. When I run the stylesheet from Oxygen, the output is in German as expected. When I use the command line for saxon9he or xproc, the output is in english. I'd like to have it in german instead.

Source (any source file will do) `source.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root/>
```

XSL file `transformation.xsl`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <foo>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(),'[FNn]','de',(),())"/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the XProc file (`showdate.xpl`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:declare-step xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc"
  xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step" version="1.0">

  <p:input port="source" sequence="false">
    <p:document href="source.xml"/>
  </p:input> 

  <p:output port="result" sequence="true">
    <p:empty/>
  </p:output> 

  <p:xslt> 
    <p:input port="stylesheet"> 
      <p:document href="transformation.xsl"/> 
    </p:input> 
    <p:input port="parameters">
      <p:empty/>
    </p:input>
  </p:xslt>

  <p:store href="out.xml"/>
</p:declare-step>
```

This is how I run the xproc file from my Mac Terminal:

```
export CLASSPATH=...../lib/calabash.jar:....../lib/saxon9he.jar
java com.xmlcalabash.drivers.Main showdate.xpl
```

And the result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>[Language: en]Thursday</foo>
```

whereas I'd like to have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>Donnerstag</foo>
```

How can I get the result I'd like to have with xproc / calabash?

Comment: It might be an issue with the saxon version. Looks like 'he' does not support localization but 'pe' and 'ee' do.

Answer (score 0):

@topskip is correct. Oxygen uses Saxon EE which comes with localization support for a number of languages (the same goes for Saxon PE).

Saxon HE (which Calabash uses by default) does not come with out-of-the-box localization support, hence the English output. Having said that, however, there is apparently a way to configure localization in Saxon HE as well - see [Saxon documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/configuration/configuration-file/config-localizations.html).